# Network interface still negotiates 10 Mbps link when computer is down

Tags: windows-10, networking, speed, wake-on-lan

I have a PC (Windows 10) that, when powered off, still negotiates a link with the switch at 10 Mbps.

As soon as the host is up, the speed is renegotiated at 1000 Mbps.

I was wondering what this was for - I presume for Wake-On-Lan?

Comment: If you disable Wake-On-Lan does the behavior you describe stop?

Comment: Without seeing the documentation for your motherboard and firmware, we can only guess things like "Wake on LAN" or "Lights-Out Management".